# Access ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator from controller to check bufferSize

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

I am using websocket to transfer text file content to client, for large file getting below exception
`Buffer size 1052364 bytes for session exceeds the allowed limit 1048576`

This is thrown from ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.java, and connection is terminated.

I don't want connection to be terminated, instead want to pause sending data to client, wait till the existing buffer flushed to client and resume.
How can I access ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator instance from controller class, so that I can check bufferSize and decide whether to send data to client or wait.

Following are some of the link I found, but they don't explain how to access ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21677

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20638

Thanks